# Why dont I get the downloaded percentage?

Tags: java, download

One of the classes of the program I am making is a Download Manager. This is the main code where I handle the download and its percentages.

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
        {
            downloadedPerc += (count/getModPackSize())*100;
            System.out.println(downloadedPerc);
            progressBar.setValue((int) downloadedPerc);
            label.setText(downloadedPerc + "%");
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
```

`downloadedPerc` is of type double. As a console output, I am getting 0.0 all the time. Why could this be happening?
My download is now very slow, of about 5kb/sec, and if i delete the % calculations, the download is considerably faster, why could this be?

Comment: Just for debugging, try printing `System.out.println("Setting progressbar value to " + (int) downloadedPerc + ". Minimum possible value is " + progressBar.getMinimum() + ". Maximum possible value is " + progressBar.getMinimum());` Also, have you ensured that the component is visible? Try doing `progressBar.setStringPainted(true)`. This will paint a string on the progressbar, if it is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this statement:

```
downloadedPerc += (count/getModPackSize())*100;
```

`count` should be of type double or you should convert the numerator to double.

For example: `downloadedPerc += (count*1.0/getModPackSize())*100;` would work fine.

Comment: This fixes the console output but my JFrame now is blank, a rectangle with a white background.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember it correctly, using progress bar is not simple. you will need property change event listener, action listener and swing worker. The downloading task has to be in different thread than the swing component otherwise it will freeze. Try to follow the instruction on Java tutorial website here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Here is the direct link to the code:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java